# Upload and Download File over Remote Node without Input Tag as File type

Tags: java, testing, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am Automating a Scenario for Web Application Over Windows which includes the File And Images to be Uploaded to a website, and on my local it is working fine through robot class **

- but when i execute my tests over Jenkins my jobs get failed. I need to Upload my file to a web site executing over Remote machine.

**

- **For File Upload :-**
  I cannot simply upload the file using send keys method since The Input tag doesn't have File Type i.e. input[type!='file'].
  Are there any other solutions to achieve this without using Robot Classes and Auto-It.

**

- For File Download:-

**
And I also need to download the File from a web Application over remote and verify that it has been downloaded successfully provided there is no API for this.
When the file gets downloaded over the remote, I am not able to verify that whether it has been downloaded or not since Remote Machine execution is not visible.
Is there any way to achieve this, kindly please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As  you are using remote desktop for execution of scripts which would fail robot class action calls as it needs screen to be unlocked. 
For the better results try using AutoIt is a free ware tools used for such purposes.

AutoIt will identify browse file objects and perform actions on it as Selenium does on Web applications.

Identify the Windows control, through AutoItV3 Windows Info tool.

More detailed steps to use AutoIt is present in the below link:
https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/autoit-tutorial-to-download-write-autoit-script/

Thanks and regards,

Sandeep Jaju